# как избавиться от ошибки если в url есть кириллица?

Tags: flutter, dart, dio

у меня поиск работает так что текст встраивается в url `https://testapi.com/api/product/search/{строка}`

но когда я пишу на кириллице получаю ошибку,

ошибка следующая: `"Invalid HTTP header field value: "й""` то есть `й` это то что я ввожу

```
flutter: ╔╣ Request ║ GET
flutter: ║  https://testapi.com/api/product/search/%D0%B9
flutter: ╚══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
flutter:
flutter: ╔╣ DioError ║ DioExceptionType.unknown
flutter: ║  null
flutter: ╚══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

как вы справляетесь с такой проблемой, может интерцептор есть специально для этого?

Comment: Ошибка точно на стороне клиента? Потому что кириллица была правильно преобразована в запросе. Вот только сервер похоже вернул в одном из полей кириллицу, а не эскейпы, поэтому dio возмутился. Вообще, можно много фантазировать без примера кода, а также http-заголовков запроса и ответа.